# Collapse all totals in a pivot table in Google Sheets by Google Sheets API and Python

Tags: python, google-sheets, pivot-table

I created a pivot table in Google Sheets through the API in python.
But, I am unable to collapse rows with totals. I just can't find a solution to do that. I am using `batchUpdate` function to create pivot table.

Is there any possibility?

[image: google sheets example view]

Here is the code I created to do the pivot table.

```
def create_pivot_table(self):
    spreadsheet = self.google_drive.SHEETS.spreadsheets()   
    #result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=self.file_id, range='Sheet1!B1:B10').execute()
    requests = []
    # Change the spreadsheet's title.
    # [START sheets_pivot_tables]
    requests.append({
        'updateCells': {
            'rows': {
                'values': [
                    {
                        'pivotTable': {
                            'source': {
                                'sheetId': self._get_sheet_id_by_name('Sheet1'),
                                'startRowIndex': 0,
                                'startColumnIndex': 0,
                            },
                            'rows': [
                                {
                                    'sourceColumnOffset': 8,
                                    'showTotals': True,
                                    'sortOrder': 'ASCENDING'
                                },
                                {
                                    'sourceColumnOffset': 1,
                                    'sortOrder': 'ASCENDING',
                                    'showTotals': True,
                                }
                            ],
                            'values': [
                                {
                                    'summarizeFunction': 'SUM',
                                    'sourceColumnOffset': 16
                                },
                                                                    {
                                    'summarizeFunction': 'SUM',
                                    'sourceColumnOffset': 17
                                },
                                                                    {
                                    'summarizeFunction': 'SUM',
                                    'sourceColumnOffset': 18
                                }
                            ],
                            'valueLayout': 'HORIZONTAL'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            'start': {
                'sheetId': self._get_sheet_id_by_name('PivotTable'),
                'rowIndex': 0,
                'columnIndex': 0
            },
            'fields': 'pivotTable'
        }
    })

    body = {
        'requests': requests
    }

    response = spreadsheet.batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=self.file_id, body=body).execute()
    return response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for `PivotGroupValueMetadata` :

> collapsed  boolean
>
> True if the data corresponding to the value is collapsed.

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/pivot-tables#pivotgroupvaluemetadata

And check :

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/pivot-tables#edit_pivot_table_columns_and_rows

> Collapses the column for each Region, with the exception of "West",
>   hiding the Salesperson group for that region. This is done by setting
>   collapsed to true in the valueMetadata for that column in the Region
>   column group.

Comment: Yes, it works, I was not sure if PivotGroupValueMetadata was the right place to do it.