# collapse subtotal in Goode sheet pivot table

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

how to collapse all to subtotal in Google sheet pivot table? (e.g when user land on the page, they see the corporate IT Total, advertising Total only but can click the + sign to expand for more details) Based on the research it seems to require me to use API([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62422224/collapse-all-totals-in-a-pivot-table-in-google-sheet-by-google-sheet-api-and-pyt) to the Stackflow thread)? Is there an easy way to do it[image]

Answer (score 0):

just needed to right click the subtotal you want to collapse.
[image]